# Read "Evaluated" Spring property values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

My current application.yaml has -

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: app-1
          uri: ${services.app1.host}/pages/
          predicates:
            - Path=/pages/**
        - id: app-2
          uri: ${services.app1.host}/content/
          predicates:
            - Path=/content/**

services:
  app1:
    host: http://app1.hostname:8080
  app2:
    host: http://app2.hostname:8080
```

In my app I need to get "evaluated" values of gateway route uri's

If I read all the values using `Environment` and loop over all properties, I get uri's with embedded variables like `${services.app1.host}`.

Also, I don't want to use `@Value` for each route/uri combo.

How do I get a Map of all evalued values under `spring.cloud.gateway.routes` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ConfigurationProperties` on a new class containing the mapped property values:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.cloud.gateway")
public class RouteProperties {
    private List<RoutePropertyEntry> routes;

    //Getter and setter for routes
}
```

With a POJO to map each route entry:

```
public class RoutePropertyEntry {
    private String id;
    private String uri;
    private List<String> predicates;

    //Getters and setters...
}
```

And retrieve the property values like this:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(RouteProperties.class)
public class SomeLogicClass {
    private final RouteProperties routeProperties;

    //Your logic here
}
```

Comment: I figured out exactly same solution few minutes back